# P≠NP, yet NP=co-NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I know , if P = NP then it can easily be proven that P = NP = Co-NP. But I was wondering,
if we assume  P≠ NP, also then  can it be proven that, NP =co-NP??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the open question NP=co-NP the same as P=NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9795/is-the-open-question-np-co-np-the-same-as-p-np)

Comment: Yeah It says , it is possible . But how ?

Comment: The reason to *have* a complexity class like co-NP is because it is not necessarily the same as NP. If P=NP then they are provably the same. If they were also provably the same if P≠NP, then NP=co-NP would be true regardless of whether P=NP.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know anything either way: it is consistent with our knowledge so far that $\mathsf{P\not=NP}$ and $\mathsf{NP=coNP}$, *and* it is consistent with our knowledge so far that $\mathsf{P\not= NP}$ and $\mathsf{NP\not=coNP}$.

Of course in some sense that's a purely *negative* statement since it's just about the limits of our current knowledge, not really about the mathematics itself. Here's an actual theorem which says, in a precise sense, that the "standard" tools of complexity theory cannot show anything about $\mathsf{NP}$ vs $\mathsf{coNP}$ even assuming $\mathsf{P\not=NP}$:

> There are oracles $A$ such that $\mathsf{P}^A\not=\mathsf{NP}^A$ and $\mathsf{P}^B\not=\mathsf{NP}^B$ but $\mathsf{NP}^A=\mathsf{coNP}^A$ and $\mathsf{NP}^B\not=\mathsf{coNP}^B$.

This should recall the [Baker-Gill-Solovay theorem](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/106671/18-405j-fall-2001/contents/lecture-notes/01lec6.pdf) that $\mathsf{P}$ vs. $\mathsf{NP}$ cannot be decided via *relativizing* methods. The proof is similarly a forcing argument, but it's a bit more intricate. I'll add a reference once I can track it down.

(I do not know whether we similarly have a "natural proofs" barrier here. I suspect we do, but that argument is more involved.)

Comment: @LukeMathieson Whoops, fixed! (I mean, I wasn't *wrong* ... :P)

Comment: Indeed, it was correct :D